# How to modify the mime message in editable email plugin in jenkins

Tags: email, jenkins-plugins

i'd like to modify the email message i send from jenkins. how can i do it?
i tried to use msg variable and set the content using msg.setContent("this is the string i want in the email body")
but it failed
any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced same task:

```
msg.setContent("Test content", 'text/html')
```

worked for me.

I guess possible types are 'text/html' and 'text/plain', check that you are changing the proper one.

Answer (score 0):

`msg.setContent` doesn't send messages if the `GString` type passed as content.

Don't forget to convert `GString` to `java.lang.String`

Use `toString()`

```
def gStringContent = "Hellow ${name}"
logger.println 'Content type is ' + gStringContent.getClass()
msg.setContent(gStringContent.toString(), 'text/html')
```

Use explicit typing `String`

```
String gStringContent = """Hello $name
Goodby ${name}"""
logger.println 'Content type is ' + gStringContent.getClass()
msg.setContent(gStringContent.toString(), 'text/html')
```

etc.

That's was my trouble. Fixed.