# Trying to send an email through a groovy shell script

Tags: email, groovy

today I was trying to replace a bash script with a groovy script. Everything runs smooth and I managed to use the `execute()` command to invoke other command.

Then I was trying to send an email with a subject:

```
mail -s "this is a test" my.mail@example.com < mail.tmp
```

turned into

```
'mail -s "this is a test" my.mail@example.com < mail.tmp'.execute()
```

does not work since groovy will split up the one argument `"this is a test"` into four arguments `"this` `is` `a` `test"`.

So far so good. Google helped me to turn this into

```
['mail', '-s', "this is a test", 'my.mail@example.com', '<', 'mail.tmp'].execute()
```

Now the subject is recognized as one parameter, but the `<` is also recognized as parameter and not as the file redirection.

Any idea how I could solve this?

PS: no, I would not like to use java code for sending mail since I guess the code will be more complex. But if you have a java one-liner, you are welcome...

Comment: Not a one liner, but has the advantage that it will work ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833892/how-to-send-html-template-as-mail-using-groovy

Comment: @tim_yates Maybe I could put this in a helper class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to handle writing the output from the process to a file ...

```
new File('mail.tmp').withWriter { it << """mail -s "this is a test" my.mail@example.com""".execute().getText() }
```

I only tested above with "ls -al" as the command and it worked as expected, I'm not sure if a longer running process would require you to tweak the way you go about it-- if so you might need to use waitForProcessOutput:

```
new File('mail.tmp').withWriter { """mail -s "this is a test" my.mail@example.com""".execute().waitForProcessOutput(it, it) }
```

Comment: I guess this is the cleanest solution - thanx!

Comment: I thought the OP's original question was send the content of the mail.tmp.  not get the mail and save to mail.tmp.

Answer (score 1):

Found another solution which looks easier to me, but I guess isn't as clean as the one provided by @chrixian:

```
['sh','-c','mail -s "this is a test" my.mail@example.com < mail.tmp'].execute()
```

this command creates another shell in order to execute the mail command. This way, the  `'mail -s "this is a test" my.mail@example.com < mail.tmp'` is interpreted by a shell and it knows how to correctly handle the parameters and `<` symbol.

Drawback: it works on *nix systems. For windows systems, the shell is executed in a different way.