# Closure compiler does not write out errors

Tags: grails, groovy, google-closure-compiler

I have a Groovy script that runs the closure compiler latest version.

```
def command = "java -jar $compiler --js $orderedDependencies --js_output_file $minFilename --create_source_map $mapFilename --compilation_level WHITESPACE_ONLY --source_map_format=V3 --language_in=ECMASCRIPT5 --debug --formatting=PRETTY_PRINT"
command.execute(null as List, outputDir).waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
```

When I use it without the `--language_in` option, I get error output.  When I add the command option, I don't get any error output, but it breaks somewhere, because nothing gets created and the web interface is broken.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

Comment: `--source_map_format=V3` is completely unnecessary. Only v3 source maps are supported. This isn't your main problem though.

Comment: Did you test the usage of the closure compiler in the shell before you are trying to script it?

Comment: Yes. It compiles without any problems and prints out warnings only.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth thanks, I realized that and just haven't removed it. I think it used to be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem is since the code you provided isn't enough the reproduce it. 
But chances are that you are searching in the wrong place: the `.execute()` command can be quite annoying. Take a look at this question to get some ideas on what could go wrong and how to solve it: [Trying to send an email trough a groovy shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751118/trying-to-send-an-email-trough-a-groovy-shell-script/20758136#20758136)

Comment: Interesting... I'll try that and get back to you.